# Textbox to display function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with my first project for the semester. Using JavaScript I'm supposed to create a magic 8 ball simulator. The simulator needs a button that that says "shake it" which, when clicked, displays a random saying from my GetSaying() function in a read only textbox. This is where I get a little lost. How do I go about specifying a textbox I would like the saying to be displayed in?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Magic 8 Ball!</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*Styles will go here*/


</style>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="Show()">Shake it!</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function Show() {
            document.write(GetSaying());
        }

        function GetSaying() {

            var pool = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", 
                        "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes",
                        "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", "Signs point to yes", 
                        "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", 
                        "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", 
                        "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful"];

            return (pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*pool.length)]);
        }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: you can define a text box by using <input type="text> or <textarea>

Comment: Thanks @ChaoticNadirs Though my code above does not reflect this, I have a text box in my HTML, I just am having trouble figuring out how to get the returned value from GetSaying() to appear in my text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `document.getElementById()` to get your `input` and then set its value.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5aozoxv7/)

```
<button type="button" onclick="Show()">Shake it!</button>
<input id="saying" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Show() {
        document.getElementById("saying").value = GetSaying();
    }

    function GetSaying() {

        var pool = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", 
                    "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes",
                    "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", "Signs point to yes", 
                    "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", 
                    "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", 
                    "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful"];

        return (pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*pool.length)]);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I appreciate that. Seeing the code and how it actually works helped me out a ton. I still have a lot more to do, but I have all that down. Thanks again.